# How do I find the area of this figure? Geometry 1

Tags: geometry

[image]

I've been doing these questions for hours and I've just got stumped on this one.  I know that if I multiply the 3.5 and 2 I can find the area of that part of the figure, but not the outer triangles. I'm not sure were to go on from there.

Comment: Use Pythagoras to find the height of the outer triangles. You know that the ticks across the hexagon's side mean they are _all_ 2 cm long, right?

Comment: Interestingly, with those given values, the hexagon is _almost_ regular. (Or it could actually be regular, within measurement errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lower (and upper) isosceles triangle can be cut into two right triangles. Use Pythagoras to find the third side of these.

Comment: How did you know they were isosceles?

Comment: @rear: Each of them has one 3.5 cm side and two 2 cm sides. A triangle with two sides of the same length is isosceles.